# SVG Animation with CSS3

Tags: svg

I had make a spelling mistake during my SVG but just fixed and it works perfectly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version:    6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-   background="new 0     0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
    <circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-    dasharray="12" cx="49.833" cy="49.833" r="49.833">
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" 
               attributeType="XML" 
              type="rotate" 
              from="0 50 50"
              to="360 50 50"  
              dur="10s"  
              repeatCount="indefinite">
</animateTransform>
</circle>

</svg>
```

The outer circle rotates at an infinite time

Comment: trabsform is not a valid attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

Please test your example before you post.  The preamble of what you posted doesn't even parse in the browser.

Once you correct the misspelling "trabsform" to "transform" it should work.  Here's a corrected version:

```
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
 width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0     0 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#00AEEF" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="12" cx="49.833" cy="49.833" r="49.833">
<animateTransform  attributeName="transform" 
           attributeType="XML" 
          type="rotate" 
          from="0 50 50"
          to="360 50 50"  
          dur="10s"  
          repeatCount="indefinite">

</animateTransform>
</circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I had forgotten the spelling mistake during the troubleshooting process.
Will look at it better next time. thank you

Answer (score -1):

I don't know svg, but I know angles:  0° = 360°.

Maybe you should do a first transfrom from="0 50 50" to="180 50 50" then when this one is ended, do a second transfrom from="180 50 50" to="360 50 50"